# What to do with the /RST pin?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, schematics, gate-driving

I'm using [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc21732-q1.pdf?ts=1616051233695&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) gate driver IC. My question is, do I have to externally pull up the /RST pin? Because it can't be left floating, but I don't get the part that says "pulled down internally".

In the datasheet this is mentioned,

[image]

So is this correct to be connected like this?

[image]

Comment: Datasheet says: "RST/EN pin needs to be pulled up to enable the device; when the pin is pulled down, the device is in disabled status.With a 50kΩ pull down resistor existing, the driver is disabled by default."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulled down internally means there is a pull-down resistor inside the chip. If it was an internal pull-up then you don't technically need an external pull-up resistor but may want one anyways for noise immunity.

Since it is a pull-down internally, you most definitely need an external pull-up resistor. The internal pull-down is probably a very high resistance so if you pull-up with a lower resistance it form a voltage divider where the voltage is still high enough to keep it out of reset.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So like Lars mentioned, if pull down resistor is 50 kohm, then I should put a higher like 100 kohm pull up resistance?

Comment: No. A divider with 100K on top and 50K on bottom will produce a voltage of 1/3 of the rail. Which is the very upper edge of a LO voltage and likely into the gray area. You are trying to Pull UP so you need a lower resistor. so the divider output voltage is much closer to the rail. You you want something more like 10K or lower so the divider output voltage is 5/6 of the rail voltage or higher.